# Issues trying to Authorize with Graph API in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, authentication, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to connect to the MS Graph with VBA. I've managed to do so with PowerShell with the exact same App API but when trying with VBA it doesn't seem to want to work.

This is the code:

```
Function GetToken()

    Dim tokenReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim userReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim urltoken As String
    Dim accessToken As String
    Dim Json As Object
    Dim Json2 As Object

    'Token URL
    urltoken = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<MyTenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    
    'Getting Access Token
    tokenReq.Open "POST", urltoken, False
    tokenReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    tokenReq.send ("scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<MyClientID>&client_secret=<MyClientSecret>")
    
    Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(tokenReq.responseText)
    accessToken = Json("access_token")
    
    'Graph API Request
    userReq.Open "GET", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?", "False"
    userReq.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer <accessToken>"  'This line is Causing Issues
    userReq.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
    userReq.send
    
    MsgBox (userReq.responseText)

End Function
```

When I run this, I get the message box saying:

*{"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217","innerError":{"date"* etc...

I've tried to find how to fix this error but I couldn't find anything and tried what I could from other forums and other people running into the same issue with other languages.

From what I've found, I think it's the Authorization Header of the actual API request as I do get the Access Token from the first request but I've tried anything to structure that header correctly, I've attempted to use the token_type from the original request, showing up with the same error.

I'm not that experienced with VBA so any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Probably best to clear that I'm using the App Registration in Azure AD and trying to run this request in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please make sure you have correctly config App services ,for reference please follow docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=ps.

[image: CompactToken parsing failed]

Comment: Thanks, but not sure why you want me to configure and app. I'm using the App Registrations in Azure AD. Sorry if I didn't make this clear, I probably worded this wrongly. Also I'm fairly certain this isn't an issue on the Azure side as I was able to make a successful request in PowerShell (By getting the Token and using Invoke-GraphRequest) and can't see what's going wrong on the VBA side as it should be configured the exact same way I did so in PowerShell.